# Container to Container communication - Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, networking, containers, docker-container, docker-network

I am a newbie to docker . I am using docker for windows on Windows 10 .
I have created a docker container application (spring boot) which need to communicate with a rabbitmq - which is again inside a container
both  of them are using the same docker network(default bridge network) but when I try to connect to rabbitmq(port 5672) the connection get refused.I am using the container IP (172.17.0.2 for rabbitmq) . If I run the connecting application outside docker container and connect to a mapped rabbitmq port  for my local machine it works. Deoesn't the containers connected to same docker network cannot communicate with each other using the docker ports?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure, that the ports are exposed. When starting the rabbitmq container, open/map the port: `-p 5672:5672`.

Also, on Docker for Windows, you can query from container to container using the special DNS name `host.docker.internal` (see documentation: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds).

Comment: "query from container to container" from the doc this is for container to host not to another container "CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST"